# How can I create a table with a dynamic name (based on current_date) and reference to it in INSERT statements?

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, teradata

At the moment I have to rerun data selection query every month, where I create one base table. This table is named something like `MyDB.MyTable_Current_Date`, so for today that would be `MyDB.MyTable_201811` using YYYYMM date format.

Instead of having to set the name manually (using ctrl + h), I would like this to be done automaticaly. My goal is that I can open the SQL and run the query where the the table that is created is `MyTable_YYYYMM`.

Note: eventually I want to also let the SQL run automatically every month, but for now this is a nice first step for my understanding.

I made the below **stored procedure**. The problem is that if I want to do an `alter table` or `insert into` statement, I cannot (or don't know how to) refer to the table that was created.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DB.table_yymm
(
IN      db_name VARCHAR(128), 
    tbl_name    VARCHAR(128)
    )
BEGIN
    DECLARE create_name VARCHAR(261) 
    ;   
    DECLARE sql_stmt    VARCHAR(600)
    ;

    SET create_name = db_name || '.' || tbl_name || CAST(
                                                    (CURRENT_DATE (FORMAT 'yymm'))
                                                    AS CHAR(4)
                                                    )
    ;
    SET sql_stmt = 'CREATE TABLE ' || create_name || ' (testvar char(1))' || ';' ;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;         
END;

CALL prd_work_lm.table_yymm('My_DB', 'My_Table')
```

Should I do this using a **stored procedure**, or using a **user defined function**?

It would be ideal if I could simply refer to some function, for example:
`CREATE TABLE DB.My_UDF(<My_DB>, <My_Table_Name>)`

Could you help me by providing an example of a code sample?

Comment: Have you considered just generating future tables, then choosing the one you want at a later time?

Comment: I don't see how that would solve the issue. Either way the SQL needs to rerun, so the tables are up to date. What I want is that the table name is created in function of today's date.

Comment: If you created the tables already, you can query sys.tables to find the one you need, and insert into it.

Comment: You mean tables without data in it? Or with data? The problem is that if I fill the tables now with all the data, it will be outdated in 1, 2, etc. month's time. Could you provide a code sample of what you mean?

Comment: You may have a good reason for doing it like this, but the normal design approach would be _one_ table with an extra column for the date. Unless you have a really good reason, you shouldn't be doing it this way

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think 'your' concern is that I would be creating many tables over time. One of the reasons I want to do it this way, is because the table would become quite large quite quickly over time otherwise. For example, one of the monthly tables has about 1.5million records / rows each month. A second reason is that this is the 'way of working' at my client. They want to have different tables because they are used to it and think it is clearer when looking things up.

Comment: @Anonymous: Of course 1.5 million rows is a small number for Teradata, even with 1.5 billion it would be no problem. Just partition the table, e.g. `range_n(datecol between date '2000-01-01' and date '2035-12-31' each intervak '1' month)'. You could still simulate those YYYYMM tables with views.

Comment: You typically manage large record counts not by splitting into physical tables, but by using partitioning and indexes. If it works, fine. Just be aware that this a “declarative” approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initially creating the new table `MyDB.MyTable_201811` and use it throughout your script you can simply create a table with a known name, e.g. `MyDB.MyTable_000000`. Now this name is used and renamed as last step.

This is a slight variation of an existing SP to rename a table from `'..._000000'` to `'..._yyyymmdd'`:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE rename_table_to_yyyymm
(
  IN db_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET Unicode,
  IN tbl_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET Unicode,
  OUT msg VARCHAR(600) CHARACTER SET Unicode
) SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
   DECLARE old_name VARCHAR(261)  CHARACTER SET Unicode;
   DECLARE new_name VARCHAR(261)  CHARACTER SET Unicode;

   DECLARE sql_stmt VARCHAR(600)  CHARACTER SET Unicode;

   SET old_name  = '"' || Coalesce(NullIf(db_name,''), DATABASE) || '"."' 
                       || Coalesce(tbl_name, '') || '"';

   SET new_name  = '"' || Coalesce(NullIf(db_name,''),DATABASE) || '"."' 
                       || Trim(Trailing '0' FROM tbl_name)-- remove '000000' at the end of the table name
                       || '_' || To_Char(Current_Date, 'YYYYMM') || '"';

   SET sql_stmt = 'RENAME TABLE ' || old_name || ' AS ' || new_name || ';'; 

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;

   SET msg = ' Table ' || old_name || ' renamed to ' || new_name;

END;
```

Comment: That's a clever solution. So if I understand you correctly, I will create table `MyDB.MyTable_000000` each month, and change this table's name each month at the end of the query to `MyDB.MyTable_yyyymm`. Correct?

Comment: @Anonymous: Yep

Comment: Would it be easier to copy from mytable_000000 into a new table, so you don't have to recreate the old one each time?

Comment: @Andrew: You have to create a new table anyway, and then it's rename vs. Insert/Select plus Delete :-)